# Remove page numbering only in one page and restart then

Tags: numbering

I added an empty page after the title and I want the page numbering to start after that empty page. With this preamble the numbering doesn't show in any page:

```
\documentclass[11pt, spanish]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\topmargin -2.0cm \oddsidemargin -0.04cm \evensidemargin -0.04cm
\textwidth 16cm \textheight 24.0cm
\parskip 7.2pt
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{[\theenumi]}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %espai entre linees
\rmfamily 
\date{}
\begin{document}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\title
{\textbf{UNIVERSIDAD AUTÓNOMA DE BARCELONA}\\
FACULTAD DE CIENCIAS\\
\vspace{5mm} 
MÁSTER UNIVERSITARIO EN HISTORIA DE LA CIENCIA:\\
CIENCIA, HISTORIA Y SOCIEDAD\\
\vspace{5mm}
\vspace{5mm}
Módulo M1: La ciencia en la historia}
\vspace{5mm} 
\vspace{5mm} 
\author{Florit Gual, Martí\\ \\
    NIU: 1461598}
\maketitle  
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Comment: You set `\pagestyle{empty}` in the second line after `\begin{document}`. This means no page numbers in the entire document.

Comment: At least until you reset to \pagestyle{plain}.  You might also need \setcounter{page}{1}.

Comment: With this preamble:
\begin{document}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\title
\maketitle  
\setcounter{page}{1} I get the right numbering but there is still a '2' in the empty page between the title and the page number '1' that I want to remove.

Comment: OK. I've solved it by inserting \thispagestyle{empty} between \null and \newpage in \afterpage

Comment: The `ucs` package does no good.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `titlepage` environment. And the `geometry` package to adjust the page parameters. Here is a sketch.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[text={16cm,24cm},centering,top=2cm]{geometry}
\parskip 7.2pt
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\LARGE
{\bfseries UNIVERSIDAD AUTÓNOMA DE BARCELONA}\\
FACULTAD DE CIENCIAS\\[5mm]
MÁSTER UNIVERSITARIO EN HISTORIA DE LA CIENCIA:\\
CIENCIA, HISTORIA Y SOCIEDAD\\[10mm]
Módulo M1: La ciencia en la historia\\[10mm]
Florit Gual, Martí\\[5mm]
    NIU: 1461598
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{titlepage}
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\cleardoublepage

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```